# Run Robotium Black-box test in Android studio

Tags: android, robotium, black-box-testing

I have Robotium black-box tests which I use to test apps without the source code.
I can run the tests from Eclipse ADT, but I can't run them from Android Studio. In Android Studio I get an error: "Empty test suite." "No tests were found"

How can I Robotium tests without having the source of the apps, in Android Studio?
Should the test project have any special structure?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have specified the test application in the `build.gradle` file. In `defaultConfig` section, add `testApplicationId "com.external.apptotest"`